# Log-likelihood of a finite mixture distribution (PDF overflowing)

Tags: machine-learning, computational-statistics, mixture-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I'm trying to use a finite mixture of Dirichlet distributions in a project, but am encountering problems with the PDF becoming so large for input values close to 0 that it overflows to infinity (as you might expect with certain parametrisations of the Dirichlet distribution). Ideally I'd like to use log-likelihood instead, but I'm not aware of how to calculate the log-likelihood for a mixture model, and I haven't been able to find anything on the subject on Google. Could anyone point me in the direction of how this would be calculated practically?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+overflow and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+underflow.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+sum+exp also turns up useful solutions.

Comment: Ah, it seems the log-sum-exp trick is indeed what I want. I will give that a go. Thank you very much!